# listView in Fragment not working (not displaying)

Tags: listview, android-fragments

I have a listView inside a fragment (ListFragment is not applicable as there are other controls in the view).
It runs fine except that the list doesn't get populated. 
Logs and debug show that adapter's getView gets called and everything is fine. just nothing displayed.

Here is the Fragment

```
public class FoundFragment extends BaseFragment {

private ArrayList<Record> recordsList;
private ListView recordsListView;
private final String LOG_TAG = "FoundFragment";
private RecordsListAdapter recordsListAdapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}//end onCreate
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // The last two arguments ensure LayoutParams are inflated properly.
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.frag_found, container, false);
    return rootView;
}//end onCreateView
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    recordsListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.foundRecordsListView);

}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    new RecordsLoaderTask().execute(false);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(recordsListAdapter != null){
    recordsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
/********************************************************************/
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onDataRetrievalSucceeded(Object dataRetrieved) {
    Log.d("FoundFragment", "arrayRetrived with length of " 
                            + ((ArrayList<Record>) dataRetrieved).size());
    recordsList = (ArrayList<Record>) dataRetrieved;
    recordsListAdapter = new RecordsListAdapter(getActivity(), recordsList);
    recordsListView.setAdapter(recordsListAdapter);
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "adapterOfList is " + recordsListView.getAdapter() + "\n" + 
    "length is " + recordsListView.getAdapter().getCount());
    //TODO check here 
    if(recordsListAdapter != null){
        recordsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}//end onDataRetrievalSucceeded
}//end fragment
```

Adapter:

```
private class RecordsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<Record> recsList;
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------//        
    public RecordsListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Record> records) {
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        System.out.println("in constructor of adaapter");
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        recsList = records;
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------//
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "categories adapter get size = " + recsList.size());
        return recsList.size();
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------//
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return recsList.get(position);
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------//
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------//
     @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.records_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recordItemNameTxtView);
            holder.age  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recordItemAgeTxtView);
            holder.img = (CircularImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recordItemImgView);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }//end if 
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Record curRecord = recsList.get(position);
        /*setting data from the item into the fields*/;
        holder.name.setText(curRecord.getName());
        holder.age.setText(curRecord.getAge());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "curRecord image link is " + curRecord.getThumbURL());
        //TODO image download
        /*if(curRecord.getThumbURL() != null && !curRecord.getThumbURL().equals("")
                && !curRecord.getThumbURL().equals("null")){
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "in if b4 download image");
            holder.img.setImageBitmap(
                    ImageDownloader.DownloadImage(curRecord.getThumbURL()));

            progressDialog.cancel();
            System.out.println("after image download");
        }//end if --> imag link is available
        else{
            System.out.println("image link is not available");
        }*/
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "convertView " + 
        convertView + ", " + ((ViewHolder)convertView.getTag()).name.getText().toString());
        return convertView;
    }//end method getView
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     class ViewHolder{
        TextView name;
        TextView age;
        CircularImageView img;
    }


}//end class RecordsListAdapter
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#0000ff" >
     <ListView
    android:id="@+id/foundRecordsListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
     >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List item height was the problem.
Adjusting list item layout and setting a minimum height solved it.
Thanks to Omnia Sayed

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what is happening is your `Adapter` which is created (first) in `onActivityCreated()` is then overwritten in `onViewCreated()`.  I would suggest having a single point created your `Adapter`, such as in `onCreateView()` so it can immediately be set as the adapter for your `ListView`.  Then kick off your data downloading task.  When it completes have it create a new `List` of data and submit it to the adapter via a custom `RecordsListAdapter.replaceData()` method.  Inside of that method your adapter should swap out its backing data and call its own `notifyDataSetChanged()` so the `ListView` will ask it to re-populate views.

Comment: Adapter creation within onViewCreated() is commented. I thought creation was the issue. but it wasn't..

Comment: I'd still recommend refactoring and cleaning this up as it is hard to follow and kicking off your data load in `onActivityCreated()` could result in the data complete callback getting called before your `onCreateView()` is called, resulting in a NPE because the `ListView` hasn't been created yet.

Answer (score -1):

Change the inflater line to

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.records_list_item, null);
```